# Проблема с Material UI

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, mui

Есть хук use effect , в котором переключается выделение строки :

```
const dataGridContainerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleRowClick = (event) => {
      const selectedRow = event.target.closest('.MuiDataGrid-row');
      if (selectedRow) {
const a = document.querySelector('.Mui-selected')
        const isSelected = selectedRow.classList.contains('selected');

        if (isSelected) {
          a.style.background = "white";
          selectedRow.classList.remove('selected');
        } 
         else {
          a.style.background = "";
          selectRow.classList.add('selected');
        }
      }
    };

    const dataGridContainer = dataGridContainerRef.current;
    if (dataGridContainer) {
      dataGridContainer.addEventListener('click', handleRowClick);
    }

    return () => {
      if (dataGridContainer) {
        dataGridContainer.removeEventListener('click', handleRowClick);
      }
    };
  }, []);
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при клике на другую строку таблицы выделение снимается только с третьего клика. Как исправить?

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Извините, забыл добавить, что используется компонент DataGrid из библиотеки Material UI

Comment: Вот в этой строчке `a.style.background = "white'';` опечатки нет?

Comment: Нет, это я просто не уследил, так у меня нет там отпечатки

Comment: Может вместо переменной а попробуете использовать состояние и заменить уже состояние, а не переменную?

Comment: Дайте мне знать, если это сработает